# Why might a react app perform poorly in the layout rendering stage?

Tags: reactjs

In here we have boxes which can have children. If you click on a box, it will add a child for it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-fire-e2jes

What I struggle to understand is why does it take increasingly long to create a child as the max depth increases?

According to performance audit, the problem is not in the data structure format where you define parent for a node, rather than defining all children for a node.

[image]

So the issue is layout. From what I could find, one anti-pattern is where you read-write-read-write styles over and over which forces browser to calculate layout before each read. I don't see anything of this sort in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is definitely layout. But not your layout. 
I tried your code without loading your style.css file. 
And it works as expected.

I created a similar use case without react. Pure css here with same dom structure:

```js
const node = (id, children) => `
  <div class='node'>${id}</div>
  <div class='children'>
    <div class='nodeAndChildren'>
      ${children}
    </div>
  </div>

`

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class='nodeAndChildren'>
  ${node(0, node(1, node(2, node(3, node(4, node(5, node(6, node(7, 'end'))))))))}
</div>
`;
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.nodeAndChildren {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.node {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.children {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div id='app'/>
```

You can see how slow this is, even here.

This seems like a weird pattern matching issue for css or grid layout. 
So, i tried it only with inline styling, was still slow
https://codesandbox.io/embed/displaygrid-bug-bcgsm

My suggestion is to use css columns instead of grid. Or just flex boxes with wrap.